# Getting Migrate Error on Model Field that doesn't exist

Tags: python, django

Ran my server today and realized I had 'two unapplied migrations'. I ran the command makemigrations and it detected no change, so naturally I then ran migrate.

I get this error code on my terminal:

```
Applying Campaigns.0016_campaignrecruit_date...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", l
ine 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", l
ine 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line
288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line
335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrat
e.py", line 200, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", lin
e 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", lin
e 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", lin
e 244, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", li
ne 122, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields
.py", line 84, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py",
 line 306, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py",
 line 178, in _remake_table

    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", li
ne 240, in effective_default
    default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py",
line 767, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py",
line 1276, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py",
line 1271, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py",
line 1233, in to_python
parsed = parse_date(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 74, i
n parse_date
    match = date_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

So to me, it looks like a date field in my model campaignrecruit is getting an input that it doesn't know how to handle. Which I would understand. But the thing is I don't have a datefield in my campaignrecruit model. The Time field is intentionally commented out right now.

Here's my models.py:

```
class campaignrecruit(models.Model):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(startcampaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    volunteer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    join = models.BooleanField()
    #Time = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.volunteer)
```

What else would throw this error? Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Usually you would have migration errors when the db is not in sync with what django thinks it knows about the db state. It would help if you could upload the migration file as well.

Comment: Didn't even think about the migration files. This led to my fix, I just deleted the migration files concerned with that field - Django had two listed in the migrations folder that were throwing the error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since no one else answered, I will. As Aritra stated, I totally forgot about the migration files that are created whenever you run the migrate command. I had removed these model fields from my models and whenever I migrated again there was an error removing the files in my migrations file. After manually going in and removing the files, my error was fixed.

The database was just out of sync with what django had in its files.